# Use a block in a panel

Tags: 7, blocks, panels

Like the title says, is there a way I can use a block inside my panel? It looks like it can't be done...

As you can see here, there is no option to add a block to my panel...

[image]

Comment: Please keep screenshots to English. My answer "Miscellaneous" is "Diverse" in that screenshot, but it becomes needlessly hard to both answer your question and derive value from it later when it's not in english.

Comment: @Letharion, I'm terrible sorry, but my colleague changed the language (very stupid) and I can't change it back!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the blocks are under the "Miscellaneous" category.

I'm not sure exactly what the distinction is, but a few of them, such as user login, end up under "Widgets" instead.

Comment: Do you know the criterion by which blocks are displayed in Miscellaneous/Widgets or not? I can't seem to find the "Book navigation" block anywhere in order to put it in a panel. Although this probably is a full question in itself...

Comment: @CamilBăncioiu All "normal" blocks go there. Though I think there's actually an odd exception for some book related blocks. Check the Panels issue queue, I know there's a relevant issue somewhere. But yeah, separate question. :)

Comment: @Letharion I explored the code and found the cause in CTools, it explicitly refrains from exposing the Book Navigation block (the reason was in a comment, but I didn't understand it). Okay, no more off-topic-ness. Still, people should take note of some exceptions when it comes to blocks in Panels, so I'm leaving this here.

Comment: regarding the login block, when I enable it for one of my panels, it won't show up. All other widgets display fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You're logged in?

Comment: @CamilB: You mention of seeing something in Ctools. Can you elaborate WHERE in ctools that is please? Letharion: Do you know if the default search module enables a block here? I can't find it in my setup so i'm wondering if anyone else see's this issue.

Comment: @DigitalFire, ctools implements its own "Advanced search form", and it's categorized under "Widgets". You can see it in `ctools/plugins/content_types/search/search_form.inc`

Comment: @Letharion Yes I'm aware of that one. But it has a problem that the "results page" widget that is required to view the results of "search form" widget doesn't seem to format html correctly. Was hoping maybe I can find a way to enable the default search block somehow.

Comment: @DigitalFire As far as I can tell, `ctools/plugins/content_types/block/block.inc` implements panes for _all_ blocks, with explicit exceptions for book and profile, which is what Camil refered to above. That search block would also end up under 'Widgets'.

Answer (score 0):

If your block from a view you can use Views but If you want to add a block there is an option called widgets to add your block like poll

Comment: I can't add a poll by using widgets...

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem that I can't see block view on Miscellaneous.

My solution is go to Module menu. Find the module "Views content panes" and uninstall it. So, the block view will display on Miscellaneous of panel.

Regards,
Bien